# Force update on pointer style image without mousemove

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a pointer as part of an `ol.interaction.draw` and the possibility to update the style of the image dynamically. When the style parameters are updated the change is represented as soon as the mouse is moved.

But I want to see the change instantly. I've tried the `refresh()`, `changed()` and `renderSync()` option (where applicable) on the map, the interaction and layer and source the interaction is bound to without success. Still the change is only effective as soon the mouse is moved. Also tried to dispatch an mousemove (on document level) event did not work.

What would be the way to have the change of style being applied immediately?